# How can I convert .CR2 to .jpg?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, finder, file-conversion

Is there a simple tool that will convert .cr2 files (Canon RAW) to .jpg?

I know Preview does it well but I'm looking for something directly accessible from the contextual menu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make a custom workflow to do this as a [Finder (or even system wide) service using Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/index.html).

Look for the **Change Type of Images** action under Photos and then you just need to decide on your workflow - whether you save this as a service that can be activated by the contextual menu or perhaps make it into a drop folder so you can automate the next step of the process as well.

[image: Automator showing picture conversion action]

Comment: Err, @bmike, according to the description this doesn't work with RAW.

Comment: I could have sworn it used to work with RAW despite it not being listed - RAW support is a pain point and if they listed RAW, lots of edge case formats would fail. Lemme dig a bit to see if I can be sure CR2 from canon will work seamlessly... There will be a tool, perhaps automator, but I better check. If you want to post a CR2 sample file (I'm a nikon guy mostly) - I'd test it for you...

Comment: I rest my case, it does work with Canon RAW as input.

Comment: It Works great ! I just can't find how I convert the file in the same folder without replacing it.

Comment: Just got it. I used "Duplicate file" before converting it. Thx again !

Comment: Just an update, tried it now and it does work with cr2 files.